# How to find nodes with same children

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have following xml. Note that node n1 and n3 have same children (order can be different). How can I write an XSL transformation to identify such nodes?

```
<Document>
    <Node name="n1">
        <Item value="v1">
        <Item value="v2">
        <Item value="v3">
    </Node>
    <Node name="n2">
        <Item value="p1">
        <Item value="p2">
        <Item value="p3">
    </Node>
    <Node name="n3">
        <Item value="v3">
        <Item value="v1">
        <Item value="v2">
    </Node>
</Document>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete XSLT 1.0 solution that is more general and can handle nodes whose children may have different names.

Comment: Detailed explanation is also added.

Comment: Just because I was intrigued, I've extended the transform to handle children with any name, in any order, with any number of attributes of any name. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a complete XSLT 1.0 solution that is general enough so that it would produce correct results even when a `Node` is allowed to have children with any name**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kNodeBySign" match="Node" use="@signature"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
          select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Node">
  <Node name="{@name}">
   <xsl:variable name="vSignature">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
     <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
     <xsl:sort select="@value"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'+++',@value)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:attribute name="signature">
   <xsl:value-of select="$vSignature"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  </Node>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:for-each select=
    "Node[generate-id()
         =
          generate-id(key('kNodeBySign',@signature)[1])
         ]
    ">

    <Node name="{@name}">
      <xsl:variable name="vNodesInGroup">
        <xsl:for-each select=
          "key('kNodeBySign',@signature)[position()>1]">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:attribute name="matches">
       <xsl:value-of select="$vNodesInGroup"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </Node>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<Document>
    <Node name="n1">
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n2">
        <Item value="p1"/>
        <Item value="p2"/>
        <Item value="p3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n3">
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n4">
        <Item value="p3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n5">
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n6">
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v4"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n7">
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v4"/>
    </Node>
</Document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Node name="n1" matches="n3 n5 "/>
<Node name="n2" matches=""/>
<Node name="n4" matches=""/>
<Node name="n6" matches=""/>
<Node name="n7" matches=""/>
```

**Explanation**:

1. This is a two-pass transformation.
2. The result of the first pass is an XML fragment containing `Node` elements with their `name` attribute and one newly added attribute: `signature`. This is the concatenation of the names and values of all children (in normal, sorted form). The result of pass1 in this concrete case is the following:
3. In pass 2 we use the Muenchian method for grouping all `Node` elements by their `signature` attribute. The first `Node` in every group is represented in the output with a new attribute `matches` whose value is the space-delimited concatenation of the `name` attributes of the remaining `Node` elements in the current group.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt to do it with XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="sep" select="' '"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <Node name="{@name}">
      <xsl:attribute name="matches">
        <xsl:apply-templates 
          select="../Node[not(generate-id() = generate-id(current()))]
                         [count(Item) = count(current()/Item)]
                         [not(Item[not(@value = current()/Item/@value)])]"
           mode="check"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </Node>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node" mode="check">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When running the stylesheet with Saxon 6.5.5 against the sample input

```
<Document>
    <Node name="n1">
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n2">
        <Item value="p1"/>
        <Item value="p2"/>
        <Item value="p3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n3">
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n4">
        <Item value="p3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n5">
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node> 
    <Node name="n6">
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v4"/>
    </Node> 
    <Node name="n7">
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v4"/>
    </Node> 
</Document>
```

I get the following result:

```
<Node name="n1" matches="n3 n5"/>

<Node name="n2" matches=""/>

<Node name="n3" matches="n1 n5"/>

<Node name="n4" matches=""/>

<Node name="n5" matches="n1 n3"/>

<Node name="n6" matches=""/>

<Node name="n7" matches=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[edit]The XSLT 2.0 stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <Node name="{@name}" matches="{../Node[not(. is current())][every $item in current()/Item satisfies $item/@value = ./Item/@value]/@name}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to

```
<Document>
    <Node name="n1">
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n2">
        <Item value="p1"/>
        <Item value="p2"/>
        <Item value="p3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n3">
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n4">
        <Item value="p3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n5">
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node>    
</Document>
```

outputs

```
<Node name="n1" matches="n3 n5"/>
<Node name="n2" matches=""/>
<Node name="n3" matches="n1 n5"/>
<Node name="n4" matches=""/>
<Node name="n5" matches="n1 n3"/>
```

Comment: That seems to match any two Node elements that have one item value in common, whereas it seemed to me that the requirement was for all the item values to match.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can fix the stylesheet easily with XPath 2.0's `every`, will do so and then think about an XSLT 1.0 implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If all the child Items have to match, then I think Martin's solution needs to be modified to use

```
<Node name="{@name}" 
      matches="{../Node[not(. is current())]
                        [count(Item) = count(current()/Item)]
                         [every $c in Item/@value 
                             satisfies 
                                $c = current()/Item/@value
                         ]
                          /@name
               }"/>
```

It's possible this doesn't meet the requirement exactly, for example it will match a Node with values v1,v2,v2 if there is another node with values v1,v2,v3. But since the requirement wasn't specified very precisely, I've had to guess a little.

(Note Martin's solution is XSLT 1.0, whereas mine is XSLT 2.0. I'm not going to the effort of writing XSLT 1.0 code unless people explicitly say that's what they need.)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I had tagged the question with xslt 1.0 for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is my (HUMBLE) XSLT 1.0 approach. It's not as much elegant as others, and it might be a failure in many cases, but, according to the question, it does the job and it has also a certain degree of customization.

The check among the nodes is performed against a pattern built using a named template: `build-pattern`. For example, in your case I compare against a pattern built using all the `value` attributes of a node; that is, the first node is compared against a pattern like `v1v2v3`. The pattern is built upon elements with name `Item`. Obviously this pattern can be changed according to the requirements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Node">

        <xsl:variable name="current">
            <xsl:call-template name="build-pattern">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="matches">

                <xsl:for-each select="../Node[not(generate-id()
                    = generate-id(current()))]">

                    <xsl:variable name="node">
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-pattern">
                            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>

                    <xsl:if test="$current=$node">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="build-pattern">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$node/Item">
            <xsl:sort select="@value"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on this input:

```
<Document>
    <Node name="n1">
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n2">
        <Item value="p1"/>
        <Item value="p2"/>
        <Item value="p3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n3">
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n4">
        <Item value="p3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n5">
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node> 
    <Node name="n6">
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v4"/>
    </Node> 
    <Node name="n7">
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v4"/>
    </Node> 
</Document>
```

Produces:

```
<Node name="n1" matches="n3n5"></Node>
<Node name="n2" matches=""></Node>
<Node name="n3" matches="n1n5"></Node>
<Node name="n4" matches=""></Node>
<Node name="n5" matches="n1n3"></Node> 
<Node name="n6" matches=""></Node> 
<Node name="n7" matches=""></Node>
```

---

I've generalized the above transform to find nodes with same children:

- **of any name**
- **in any order**
- **with any number of attribute and of any name**

One would need only to replace the named template `build-pattern` with the following two:

```
<xsl:template name="build-pattern">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$node/*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@*[1]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute::*">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

For example, when the new transform is applied to the following document:

```
<Document>
    <Node name="n1">
        <Item value="v1" x="a2"/>
        <foo value="v2" x="a1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n2">
        <Item value="p1"/>
        <Item value="p2"/>
        <Item value="p3"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n3">
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v1" x="a2"/>
        <foo value="v2" x="a1"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n4">
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <xxxx value="v2"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="n5">
        <xxxx value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
    </Node> 
    <Node name="n6">
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v4"/>
    </Node> 
    <Node name="n7">
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v1"/>
        <Item value="v2"/>
        <Item value="v3"/>
        <Item value="v4"/>
    </Node> 
</Document>
```

Produces:

```
<Node name="n1" matches="n3"/>
<Node name="n2" matches=""/>
<Node name="n3" matches="n1"/>
<Node name="n4" matches="n5"/>
<Node name="n5" matches="n4"/>
<Node name="n6" matches=""/>
<Node name="n7" matches=""/>
```