# XSLT - How can I save a node from one document in another temp document and later retrieve it?

Tags: xslt

This isn't exactly what I want to do, but it's a simple case of the functionality I need. I want to alternate between processing nodes in one document and processing nodes in a temp document that was created during the processing of the original document. To do this, I want to "save" a node from the original document into the temp document so I can go back to it. I can easily "save" the node itself into the temp document, but being part of the temp document I can no longer do things like test if another node is an ancestor of that node in the original document.

I could imagine using generate-id to do this. I wouldn't save the node per se, but an id to it and then use the id to get back to the node within the original document. The problem with this approach is that I can't ask for the node whose generate-id is such and such. I could go through the tree and find it, but I'm looking for a simpler, faster access method.

Does one exist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well with XSLT 2.0 you can certainly create temporary trees as variable values and then apply XPath to them. With XSLT 1.0 there is the restriction that temporary trees are result tree fragments, to apply XPath on them you first need to apply an extension function like exsl:node-set http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html e.g. `<xsl:variable name="rtf1"><!-- create some temporary tree here --></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="t1" select="exsl:node-set($rtf1)"/><!-- now you can process t1 as normal e.g. <xsl:apply-templates select="$t1/foo/bar"/>`.

Comment: generate-id() will not work across different XMLs because these ids are different everytime you process a XML! I recommend you to copy the original XML as much as you needed into a temporary document and place some sort of marker (attribute or an additional node) into/after/before the nodes which are interesting for you. Later you can remove this marker.

Comment: @Martin I also thought about XSLT 2.0. Thanks for the node-set tip for XSLT 1.0 (didn't know of this).

Comment: You can implement yourself a `generate-id()`-like function that generates an identifier based on the name and content of the node. You can see some practical example in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438351/how-to-find-nodes-with-same-children/6440844#6440844).

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a convenient solution using keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Index every node of interest by its `generate-id()`**:

```
 <xsl:key name="kNodeById" match="node()"
  use="generate-id()"/>
```

**and to get to the node by its id `$vId`**:

```
key('kNodeById', $vId)
```

Comment: @empo: I don't understand your question -- and it seems you don't understand the OP's question. Nobody compares generate-id-s of nodes in different documents.

Comment: that's probably why I was asking you

Comment: @empo: the `key()` function works with the current document. One simply changes the current document and then uses the `key()` function.